# what is the meaning of "look and see" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

everybody. I have a problem in this part of short story “Terrified” written by C.B. Gilford. I don't understand what the sentence "Look and see." means.
This story is about Santin, a seller; he got an accident with a car on the opposite side of road. Drivers on that car, a young man and his girlfriend intended to silent Santin so no one can know that is the young man’s fault. In previous part, the young man hit Santin once already. And now, he intended to finish him.

“…

Santin saw him coming and closed his eyes.

“Wait a minute,” he heard the girl say.

“what’s the matter?” (young man)

“You’re getting blood on yourself, aren’t you?” (his girlfriend)

"I don't know." (young man)

**"Look and see."** (his girlfriend)

"Yes, I am. But what difference does it make?"

"Vince, Vince, are you crazy? They'll see the blood..." "
According to my research, website http://www.differencebetween.net says:

1. Look: "It means to direct the eyes and attention in a particular direction, but especially to examine or search for something with the eyes."
2. See: "It means to notice or become aware of something or someone by using the eyes or to observe something."

and this question [what is meant by 'look and see' in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39882/what-is-meant-by-look-and-see-in-this-sentence)  gives me some idea.

So I think The girl said "Look and see." to tell the young man "Check your body or clothes, maybe it has blood on it."
But the author use Present Continuous in her previous line "“You’re getting blood on yourself, aren’t you?”. Present Continuous can be used for future arrangement. Maybe she's trying to ask "Do you intend to let blood sprayed on your body?". If this is right, then "Look and see." means a warning.

Can you help me figure out the meaning of the sentence "Look and see." in this situation? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a warning actually by the girl. Thr girl is just trying to support her earlier comment which is telling him that he has blood on him. When he says "I don't know", she just tells him to check and see that she is telling him the truth. It's like he would see the blood if he looked. The girl is arguing here that he didn't even look to see, so she tells him to look at his body so he can see the blood (and that she is asking a genuine question).

Comment: Look & see is an idiomatic paring - do one, then the other will become apparent.